# How do I rename all files in folder to user input plus count?

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I want to rename all filenames in a folder where the batch file is executed.

The file should ask the user for a name and an extension and create the following:

For exmaple:

name: horse

extension: exe

Output:

```
horse1.exe
horse2.exe
horse3.exe

@ECHO OFF
SET /P uname=Please enter your name: 
IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO Error
SET /P extension=Extension: 
IF "%extension%"=="" GOTO Error
SET COUNT=1
FOR /R %F in (*.*) do (
ren %~nF %filename%.%extension%Count+1
)
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO No input.
:End
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /P filename=Please enter your name: 
IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO Error
SET /P extension=Extension: 
IF "%extension%"=="" GOTO Error
SET COUNT=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A-D *.*') do (
   ECHO Executing: ren "%%F" %filename%!Count!.%extension%
   ren "%%F" %filename%!Count!.%extension%
   set /A Count+=1
)
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO No input.
:End
PAUSE
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

I added `ECHO` word before the `ren` command in order to see the executed commands and run the Batch file in my computer. This is the result:

```
C:\> dir /B
frame.txt
prueba.txt
prueba0.bat
prueba1.bat
test.bat

C:\> ..\test
Please enter your name: horse
Extension: exe
ren "frame.txt" horse1.exe
ren "prueba.txt" horse2.exe
ren "prueba0.bat" horse3.exe
ren "prueba1.bat" horse4.exe
ren "test.bat" horse5.exe
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

You may remove the first `@echo off` line, run the program and copy-paste the error shown besides a couple lines before the error...

Comment: Alright I tried doing as you just said, and I get the exact same output in the console, but it's still not actually renaming the files. In the console it prints out as if it has changed it, but the actual files aren't changed at all..

Comment: Note that `ECHO ren "%%F" ...` only **SHOW** the commands, and that you must use `ren "%%F" ...` in order to **EXECUTE** the commands! What I still don't understand is why the `ECHO ...` version show _correct_ commands, but with no ECHO it says "wrong syntax"... Try inserting BOTH lines: with and without the `ECHO ` part. I modified the Batch file to do this...

Comment: Okay I figured out why. It says wrong syntax because I have spaces in my file name, and of course it won't understand the syntax when it get several parameters, when it's only expecting two. Solution is just to put `""` around `%filename%!Count!.%extension%`

Answer (score -1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P filename=Please enter your name: 
IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO Error
SET /P extension=Extension: 
IF "%extension%"=="" GOTO Error

set /a x=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R %F in (*.*) do (
set /a x+=1
ren %~nF %filename%!x!.%extension%
)
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO No input.
:End
PAUSE
```

Comment: why the -1? Please explain.